# Gem not uninstalling on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

```
==> dyno-760868.log (crash) <==

/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- gbarcode (MissingSourceFile)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
    from /home/app/c6b26d71-eddb-4679-a962-fc9c69b7c8e4/vendor/plugins/barcoder/init.rb:3:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
     ... 22 levels...
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1

-----> Your application is requiring a file that it can't find.
```

My App is crashing as it can't find gbarcode - which I don't wish to use any more. I have uninstalled the gem from my development environment and wish to push it to heroku. How can I get my app booting without the gem?

Comment: check your environment file. You might still have the gem included there.

Comment: No luck - I searched the whole project and can't seem to find it anywhere :S

Comment: Checked the .gems file. Am working backwards trying to find the cause.

Answer (score 2):

You are requiring the gem through the barcoder plugin.

Uninstall **barcoder** plugin by deleting the vendor/plugins/barcoder directory and all will be fine.

Comment: Its been deleted. Conincidentally the app runs fine locally but not on Heroku. I believe it may be a ruby compiler problem - am reinstalling as we speak. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Still unsure of the exact fault.

In the end I created a new heroku app, duplicated the local files and repointed my domain names. The app now works perfectly.

This is a cheap workaround - but it seems to work.